# Tcl/tk - Get window height and width and set relative text height in grid

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I want to create a window with two text boxes one on top of another with first occupying 25% of height and next occupying 75% of height.

I tried to calculate relative height/width of toplevel win and pass into text command but didn't work (I am guessing because the units of dimension returned by wm geometry is not the same as when passed to text command)

Following is my code:

```
toplevel .t
wm geometry .t 1500x800+10+10
update
proc topAspect {args} {
    regexp {(\d+)} $args -> relAspect
    regexp {([^\d|%]+)} $args -> aspect
    regexp {(.*)x(.*)[+-](.*)[+-](.*)} [wm geometry .t] -> width height x y
    puts "width->$width height->$height x->$x y->$y"
    switch -regexp [string tolower $aspect] {
        x {
            return [expr $x + $relAspect]
        }
        y {
            return [expr $y + $relAspect]
        }
        w {
            return [expr $width * $relAspect / 100]
        }
        h {
            return [expr $height * $relAspect / 100]
        }
        default {
            log::log error "Unsupported relative aspect $aspect cannot be determined for top level window"
        }
    }
}

text  .t.text1 -height [topAspect -width 25%] -width [topAspect -width 99%]
grid .t.text1 -sticky news
text  .t.text2 -height [topAspect -width 75%] -width [topAspect -width 99%]
grid .t.text2 -sticky news
```

When I tried following - it did give me some decent GUI:

```
text  .t.text1 -height 20 -width [topAspect -width 99%]
grid .t.text1 -sticky news
text  .t.text2 -height 20 -width [topAspect -width 99%]
grid .t.text2 -sticky news
```

But i want to use the relative options. How to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to solve this is to use the grid geometry manager with weights in the right ratio and a uniform group. It will even work fine when you resize the window; Tk knows the policy itself and maintains it for you. (Internally, `grid` is a fairly sophisticated constraint solver; you can do some *really* complicated stuff with it.)

```
toplevel .t
grid [text .t.text1 -bg red]   -sticky news
grid [text .t.text2 -bg green] -sticky news

# The group name is just an arbitrary non-empty string.
# So long as it is the same on the two rows it will work as desired.
# The weights give a ratio of 1:3, i.e., 25% to one and 75% to the other.

grid rowconfigure .t .t.text1 -weight 1 -uniform group1
grid rowconfigure .t .t.text2 -weight 3 -uniform group1
```

(If you're using Tk 8.5, you'll need to specify the rows to `rowconfigure` by number instead of the often-more-convenient name of a widget in the row.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the `-height` and `-width` options for the `text` widget are given in character units, not screen units. You can fix that by further dividing by font width and height (I set them to constant values below). Remember that this is integer division!

Oooh, all those regexes… I’ve cleaned up a bit, you can take it or leave it.

```
proc topAspect {aspect relAspect} {
    set relAspect [string trimright $relAspect %]
    scan [wm geometry .t] "%dx%d%d%d" width height x y
    set fontWidth 15
    set fontHeight 15
    switch -regexp [string tolower $aspect] {
        x {
            return [expr {$x + $relAspect}]
        }
        y {
            return [expr {$y + $relAspect}]
        }
        w {
            return [expr {($width * $relAspect / 100) / $fontWidth}]
        }
        h {
            return [expr {($height * $relAspect / 100) / $fontHeight}]
        }
        default {
            log::log error "Unsupported relative aspect $aspect cannot be determined for top level window"
        }
    }
}
```

Also, you used `-width` as an argument to `topAspect` for both `-height` and `-width`: I presume that was a mistake.

```
text  .t.text1 -height [topAspect -height 25%] -width [topAspect -width 99%]
grid .t.text1 -sticky news
text  .t.text2 -height [topAspect -height 75%] -width [topAspect -width 99%]
grid .t.text2 -sticky news
```

Otherwise, I recommend Donal Fellows’s solution.

Documentation:
[* (operator)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm),
[+ (operator)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm),
[/ (operator)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm),
[expr](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm),
[for](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/for.htm),
[grid](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/grid.htm),
[proc](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/proc.htm),
[return](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/return.htm),
[scan](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/scan.htm),
[set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm),
[string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm),
[switch](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/switch.htm),
[text (widget)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/text.htm),
[wm](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/wm.htm),
[Syntax of Tcl regular expressions](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm)

Comment: Care needs to be taken parsing geometry output as it can have negative offsets in multimonitor setups. eg: `200x200+-638+77` on mine. So the `scan` statement to correctly parse that is `[scan $geometry "%dx%d+%d+%d"]` which is able to handle the negatives.

Comment: Thank you for the correction, I misunderstood the documentation of the format. But from my current understanding, the prefix could be - as well as +, possibly followed by the sign of g the number. If so, it would have to be scanned by `{%dx%d%*1[+-]%d%*1[+-]%d}` or the regular expression `{(\d+)x(\d+)[+-]([+-]?\d+)[+-]([+-]?\d+)}`.

Comment: The format WxH-X+Y (using a leading minus for the X offset is to indicate the position is from the right end of the screen -- See the comments on WM_NEGATIVE_X in tkWinWm.c. So potentially we could get `1x1--2+3` I think so yes. Looks like a regex is necessary.

Comment: The scan pattern is still simpler,  but I wouldn't hold it against anyone who wanted to use regexp instead.

Comment: There's also the optional leading =, and the size is optional:  `{=?((\d+)x(\d+))?([+-])(-?\d+)([+-])(-?\d+)}`.  I used the X documentation to determine this regexp.  I don't know if a `...++456` would be valid or not.  I am guessing not.

Comment: The docs for `wm geometry` say the same thing about the argument when setting geometry, but does the *return value* really have an (optional) equals sign and optional size?

Comment: Return value from Tcl?  Maybe not, but then some APIs simply return what the OS gives them, so I would rather be safe.  It costs nothing to have the correct RE in there.

Comment: The return value from `wm geometry`. I've never seen it return an equals sign or skip the size.

Answer (score 0):

Place worked best in this case - even on resizing the following held out the proportions well:

```
place .t.text1  -in .t -relheight .25 -relwidth .98 -relx .003 -rely .003
place .t.text2 -in .t -relheight .75 -relwidth .98 -relx .003 -rely .254
```

Is there any pitfall that anyone sees in this approach as compared to grid.

Thank you

Comment: The main issue with `place` when used like this is that it doesn't propagate sizes to the containing widget. This might or might not matter to you, depending on what's going on in the rest of your GUI. You can also fix it by binding to the `<Configure>` event on the right widgets, but that's when things can get quite complicated.

Comment: Ok - i will work with grids as you suggested and if works well wil use the same - Thanks again